# Calculate rows that haven't been updated for 30 days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hopefully someone can help with this. I have a table that looks like the below

```
CaseID      ClientID      ContactDate
23722         8283         01-JAN-2018
2322           233         04-FEB-2018
23382          833         06-FEB-2018
2324          8283         08-FEB-2018
```

What I want to do is create a stored procedure that contains a parameter called `@DT` (this will be a specified date). Once run, the stored procedure will get me a list of all `ClientID`s that have no `ContactDate` prior to 30 days of the `@DT` parameter. This will be called `contactflag`. I also want it to check the table again to see if the Client had a `ContactDate` within 7 days AFTER the `@DT` parameter, this will be called `HadNextContact` flag. An ideal output would look like this, based on `@DT` being allocated the date of `7 Feb 2018`;

```
 ClientID      ContactFlag      HadNextContact
 8283               1                1
 233                0                0
 833                0                0
```

The `ContactFlag` is set to `1` for `ClientID = 8283` because they hadn't had a `ContactDate` within the 30 days before `7 Feb 2018`. The `HadNextContact` flag was also set to was as they had a `ContactDate` within 7 days after `7 Feb 2018`.

Hopefully someone can help? Appreciated as always!

Jess

Comment: GROUP BY, use case expressions to get ContactFlag and HadNextContact.

Comment: You want these two flags for *every* ClientId in your table, right? How's your table called?

Comment: Yes every ClientID in the table. The table is called ClientCaseHistory

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use condition aggregate function with `DATEDIFF` function.

```
SELECT ClientID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,ContactDate,@DT) > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ContactFlag,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ContactDate BETWEEN @DT AND DATEADD(DAY,7,@DT) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) HadNextContact
FROM T
GROUP BY ClientID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e6668c9268a89686f1c64adb07d6d8e)

Comment: You're just missing the condition `no ContactDate prior to 30 days of the @DT parameter`.

Comment: the aggregation should be `max` rather than `count`..with count, there is a chance the flags will be > 1, if more than one row satisfies the condition.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Thanks for point out I reread the question, it need to get flag instead of count.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @dt datetime='20180207'

select
    c.ClientID,
    case
        when exists 
        (
            select 1 
            from ClientCaseHistory tb -- TableBefore
            where tb.ClientID=c.ClientID and tb.ContactDate between dateadd(day,-30,@dt) and @dt
        ) 
    then 0 else 1 end as ContactFlag,
    case
        when exists 
        (
            select 1 
            from ClientCaseHistory ta -- TableAfter 
            where ta.ClientID=c.ClientID and ta.ContactDate between @dt and dateadd(day,7,@dt)
        ) 
     then 1 else 0 end as HadNextContact
from 
    --Get all ClientIDs. Maybe you have a better table to do this, a client table?
    (
        select distinct ClientID 
        from ClientCaseHistory t
    )c
```